# JQuery tablesorter plugin - update sorting after modified rows

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I use the tablesorter 2.0, and I update the cells' value with ajax. After the call I would need to order again the rows, but the $('#thisTable').trigger('update') don't help me.

I dealing with markup inside cells, but it can't be problem.

```
 $('#thisTable').tablesorter({
   textExtraction: function(node) {
     return node.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value; 
   }
 });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

--
Kree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answer in table sorter [docs](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html). You have to trigger another event `sorton`.

Comment: Yes, I read it, but I don't know, which column was sorted before update... The sorton need the sort column(s) as parameters.

Comment: Actual sort columns are stored in: $('#thisTable').get(0).config.sortList. If it is undefined than you can add some default sorting.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code

```
//append some content to the tbody
$('table').trigger('update');    
var $sort = $('table').get(0).config.sortList;
$("table").trigger("sorton",[$sort]);
```

The above is called after I add some rows to the table body. I am able to see the $sort values but the trigger function is not sorting the newly added rows.

Comment: I enabled debug mode of table sorter. The update trigger updates the table cache, however the sorton trigger is sorting the previously cached data. So the new data is not getting sorted. To make them synchornized i put the $("table").trigger("sorton",[$sort]); in setTimoutblock with a delay of 50ms. But this is just a work around but this is not the proper fix I guess. Can somebody suggest the proper fix ?

Answer (score 1):

I've have a small change in the source code. I've added a parameter to the update event handler to ask for sorting.

`$("#MyTable").trigger('update')` will work as usual.

`$("#MyTable").trigger('update', true)` will ask for sorting after the update.

```
$this.bind("update", function (e, sort) {
   var me = this;
   setTimeout(function () {
       // rebuild parsers.
       me.config.parsers = buildParserCache(
       me, $headers);
       // rebuild the cache map
       cache = buildCache(me);
       // ADDED
       if (sort) $(me).trigger('sorton', [me.config.sortList]);
   }, 1);
});
```

Comment: this should be an accepted feature to tablesorter source. did you try to contribute this on github? not sure about the triggering of sorton though. there is probably a more direct way?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the implementation of the "update" event,
it executes the update after a timeout of 1ms.
eather this function should be rewritten in the table sorter, eather using a callback.

```
$this.bind("update", function () {
  var me = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    // rebuild parsers.
    me.config.parsers = buildParserCache(
    me, $headers);
    // rebuild the cache map
    cache = buildCache(me);
}, 1);
```